# [React]Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'type')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use react, firebase and semantic ui to make a website that can upload diaries with picture, but when I upload a diary with no picture, it show

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'type') at Object.onSubmit (NewPost.js:41:1)`

When I first finish this code, it's ok not to upload the photo, I don't know why it turn out like this.

```
const [file, setFile] = React.useState(null);
const previewUrl = file ? URL.createObjectURL(file) : "https://react.semantic-ui.com/images/wireframe/image.png";
function onSubmit() {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const documentRef = firebase.firestore().collection(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).doc();
        const fileRef = firebase.storage().ref('post-images/'+documentRef.id);
        const metadata = {
            contentType: file.type,  //problem here
        };
        fileRef.put(file, metadata).then(() => {
            fileRef.getDownloadURL().then((imageUrl) => {
                documentRef.set({
                    title,
                    content,
                    topic: topicName,
                    createdAt: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now(),
                    imageUrl,
                }).then(() => {
                    setIsLoading(false);
                    history('/posts');
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

```
return (
        <Container>
            <Header>寫日記</Header>
            <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                <Image src={previewUrl} floated="left" size="small" />
                <Button basic as="label" htmlFor="post-image">上傳圖片</Button>
                <Form.Input type="file" id="post-image" style={{display: 'none'}} onChange={(e) => {setFile(e.target.files[0])}} />
                <Form.Input placeholder="請輸入日記標題" value={title} onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
                <Form.TextArea placeholder="請輸入日記內容" value={content} onChange={(e) => setContent(e.target.value)} />
                <Form.Dropdown placeholder="選擇日記主題" options={options} selection value={topicName} onChange={(e, { value }) => setTopicName(value)} />
                <Form.Button loading={isLoading}>送出</Form.Button>
            </Form>
        </Container>
    );
```

Comment: Where do you set file? It's clearly not working as it's null

Comment: You're not checking for `file` to not be `null`. You said that this happens when no picture is uploaded. The error makes total sense because `file` is `null` since you never changed it. You should change the logic of sending your form. What should happen if no image is included? I imagine it probably shouldn't attempt to upload a picture at all. You should wrap your the lines with `fileRef` and `metadata` inside an `if (file) {`.

Comment: The `file` variable is clearly still `null` when referenced at this point in the code. Are you expecting to have a value here by then? Perhaps you should add some form validation to ensure all required field values are populated and valid so that when the form is submitted the handler has everything it needs.